# How to make a shopping cart?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm totally a beginner to Javascript, and I need to make a virtual online grocery website for my uni project. I'm stuck with making a virtual cart by using Javascript.
I successfully display the specific product detail from my database when I click on the product title, but I have no idea how I can add the specific product and display the added products in my cart.php file.I know I should use SESSION, but as I could not find some samples that using the database to display the product details.

**Below is my product.php file code:**

```
<html>
<head>
 
        
</head>
<body>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "///";
$password = "///";
$dbname = "assignment1";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection error: " . $conn->connect_error);
}



$product_name = "";
$unit_price = "";
$unit_quantity = "";
$in_stock = "";
$itemId = "";
$showNoItem = "display: none";
$showItem = "";


if (isset($_GET['data'])) {
    $itemId = $_GET['data'];
    $sql = "SELECT product_id , product_name , unit_price, unit_quantity, in_stock  FROM products where product_id=".$itemId;
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        
        $showNoItem = "display: none";
        $showItem = "";
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $product_name = $row["product_name"];
            $unit_price =  $row["unit_price"];
            $unit_quantity =  $row["unit_quantity"];
            $in_stock =  $row["in_stock"];
            break;
        }
    } else {

        $showNoItem = "";
        $showItem = "display: none";
    }
} else {
    $showNoItem = "";
    $showItem = "display: none";
}


?>

<div id="noItem" style="<?php echo $showNoItem?>">Select items from categories on the left.</div>
<div id="itemDiv" style="<?php echo $showItem?>">
    <div class="item-title">
        <span class="item-name"><?php echo $product_name?> </span>
        (<span class="item-quatity"><?php echo $unit_quantity?></span>)
    </div>
    <div class="itemDetail">

        <div class="item-desp">
            <div class="in-stock-div">In Stock: <span class="item-in-stock"><?php echo $in_stock?> </span> </div>
            <div class="price-tag-div">Price: <span class="item-price-red">$<?php echo $unit_price ?></span></div>
            <p></p>
            

            <form action="cart.php" method="get" target="cart" class="order-row" onsubmit="return validate_quantity">
                <input type="number" class="item-quatity-input spin0" min="1" value="1" name="display" id="display" onkeyup="addCartButtonCtrl()" >
                <input type="hidden" name="productId" value="<?php echo $itemId?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="productInfo" value='<?php echo "$product_name($unit_quantity)"?>'>
                <input type="hidden" name="productPrice" value="<?php echo $unit_price ?>" >


                <div class="add-cart-div">
                    <input id="cart-button" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Add to Cart" title="Add to cart." onclick="updateShoppingCart()">

                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<?php
$conn->close();

?>
</body>
</html>
```

**I tried to use the function**

```
addCartButtonCtrl(){
$action = $_GET['action'];
            switch ($action) {
                case 'Add':
                    $product_id = $_GET['productId'];
                    $product_name = $_GET['productInfo'];
                    $unit_price = $_GET['ProductPrice'];

                    
                    if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
                        $_SESSION['cart']=array();
                    }

                    $index = getItemIndex($product_id);
                    if ($index < 0) {
                        $item_array=array('product_id' => $product_id,
                                          'product_name' => $product_name,
                                          'unit_price' => $unit_price,
}
```

Comment: HInt (one of the ways) : (1) use a session variable to store those stock items added to the cart (2) if necessary, store the quantity of the items as well (3) make sure that the user can delete an item from the cart, or change its quantity (if applicable in your case)

Comment: A simple Google search will return hundreds (if not thousands) of tutorials - e.g.https://medium.com/sharing-and-learning/creating-a-shopping-cart-with-vanilla-javascript-23b2e4d8e1ef or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B20Getj_Zk4 or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YeFzkC2awTM. People should first learn how to use Google before trying to learn programming - just like we first learn arithmetic before going to differential equations.